# Finding intersections between multi line segments

Tags: postgis

I am trying to find the common intersections between several multi line segments in postgis. 
I have a solution, it seems to work for small data networks,but it takes its time for large networks.
My set up is

```
create table test(id serial, name text );
```

`ALTER TABLE  test ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);`
`select addGeometryColumn('test','the_geom',3857,'MULTILINESTRING',2);
 create table test_results(id serial, name text );
 ALTER TABLE  test_results ADD PRIMARY KEY (id); 
select addGeometryColumn('test_results','the_geom',3857,'MULTILINESTRING',2);`

Load some data

`insert into test (name,the_geom) values('Line_1',st_setsrid(ST_LineMerge( ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((1 1,2 2,3 3),(4 4 ,5 5))')),3857));
insert into test (name,the_geom) values('Line_2',st_setsrid(ST_LineMerge( ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((1 1,2 2,3 0,0 0,0 4),(4 4 ,5 5))')),3857));insert into test (name,the_geom) values('Line_3',st_setsrid(ST_LineMerge( ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((1 1,2 2,4 4,0 0,0 4),(4 4 ,5 5))')),3857));`

Compute all matching segments

```
insert into test_results(name,the_geom) select t1.name|| ' '|| t2.name as name  ,st_intersection(t1.the_geom,t2.the_geom) as  the_geom from test t1, test t2 where st_intersects(t1.the_geom,t2.the_geom) and  st_equals(t1.the_geom ,t2.the_geom)=false;
```

i.e. find every intersection in every line  where the lines are not same as each other.
It gives the following results in qgis

where 
Line 1 green 
Line 2 red 
Line 3 yellow
Combine Black

Is there a faster way of getting this to work ?
[image]